# How to highlight ListBox SelectedItem in wp8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Friends,

I am using MVVM to bind `ListBox SelectedItem` but seems it doesn't work. The list is binded successfully, but No item is selected.

XAML Page

```
<ListBox x:Name="lsbReadingChapter" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
ItemsSource="{Binding QuranText}" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle1}"
Grid.Row="1">
 ....
</ListBox>
```

MVVM Code

```
public class QuranTextViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        DataSource ds = null;
        ObservableCollection<ArabicTextWithTranslation> _quranText;
        public QuranTextViewModel(Chapter c)
        {
            ds = new DataSource();
            QuranText = new ObservableCollection<ArabicTextWithTranslation>();

            List<ArabicTextWithTranslation> texts = ds.getArabicTextWithTranslation(c);
            Recent r = DataSource.Recents;
            SelectedItem = (from grp in texts
                            where grp.ArabicText.ChapterID == r.ChapterID && grp.ArabicText.AyaID == r.AyaID
                            select grp).FirstOrDefault();
            foreach (ArabicTextWithTranslation t in texts)
            {
                QuranText.Add(t);
            }

        }
        public ObservableCollection<ArabicTextWithTranslation> QuranText
        {
            get { return _quranText; }
            set
            {
                if (_quranText != value)
                {
                    _quranText = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("QuranText");
                }
            }
        }
        ArabicTextWithTranslation _selectedItem;
        public ArabicTextWithTranslation SelectedItem
        {
            get {
                return _selectedItem; 
            }
            set
            {
                if (_selectedItem != value)
                {
                    _selectedItem = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
                }
            }
        }
}
```

The `SelectedItem` is not working, though in debug mode I can see the value in `SelectedItem`.

How to set `SelectedItem` and `Highlight` the SelectedItem?

Comment: You can apply the solution that I wrote here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596398/how-to-change-color-of-the-selected-listview-item-wp8-1/25598078#25598078

Comment: If you don't want to go the VisualManager route, then you can bind the color to your model as well, here is my solution for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070203/wp8-highlight-selecteditem-longlistselector/25101536#25101536