# How to notify the UI that it's property changed from code-behind? (WP8)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Can I notify the UI control that it's ItemsSource changed from code-behind without creating a model that inherits BindableBase class?

Here is a structure of my code-behind:

```
    public partial class Allobjects : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        ObservableCollection collectionToBeAssigned;
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            UIControl.ItemsSource = collectionToBeAssigned;
            ChangeCollection();
        }

        public void ChangeCollection() 
        {
             //here collectionToBeAssigned will be changed
        }
    }
```

Seems like AllObjects class can't inherit the BindableBase class. So, how to notify UI that I changed collection in my case? Will the simple rebinding in ChangeCollection() function help? What if I write  `UIControl.ItemsSource = collectionToBeAssigned;` again in ChangeCollection() function?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to notify that a collection has changed use an

ObservableCollection
[MSDN: ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx)

It will implement INotifyPropertyChanged property for you.

If you want to notify that a property of an item of the collection then you will have to implement a INotifyPropertyChanged for that property as well.

---

A good example of all this is my example on how to highlight selected items of the LongListSector

[WP8 Highlight SelectedItem LongListSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070203/wp8-highlight-selecteditem-longlistselector/25101536#25101536)