# Need to populate next page's listbox by executing the code on previous page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on a Windows Phone 8.1 Music Player app in C#/XAML.

When the user hits the "Next" button on the intro page and goes to the second page, he will see a listview. This listview is supposed to be populated with all the songs on the phone. But that seems to take at least 3-5 seconds and the user ends up having to look at a blank white screen until all the songs are loaded into a list and then the list is put into the listview.

My approach was to begin the population on the first page instead, so by the time the users comes arrives at the second page, either listview has already been populated or it's almost done populating.

If I stay on the first page for 3-5 seconds and then go to the next page, I can see the listview populated with all the songs fine. But instead, if as soon as the app opens, I immediately hit the button and go to the next page, then I only see the listview half-way populated. While the list eventually is able to gather all the songs, it only populates the listview to the point where it was when it reading all the songs.

MainPage.xaml.cs (First page):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.FileProperties;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace Beta
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        List<Music> source = new List<Music>();
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.setAllItems();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(Player));
        }

        private async Task getMusic(IStorageFolder folder)
        {
            var folders = await folder.GetFoldersAsync();
            if (folders != null)
                foreach (var fol in folders)
                    await getMusic(fol);

            var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                MusicProperties musicProperties = await file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
                this.source.Add(new Music(musicProperties.Artist, musicProperties.Title, musicProperties.Album));
                Player.source = this.source;
            }
        }
        private async void setAllItems()
        {
            await this.getMusic(Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.MusicLibrary);
        }
    }
}
```

Player.xaml.cs (Second page):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Threading;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Beta;
using Windows.Storage;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Storage.Search;
using Windows.Storage.FileProperties;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Beta
{
    public sealed partial class Player : Page
    {
        public static List<Music> source;
        public Player()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            this.contentList.ItemsSource = source;
            contentList.UpdateLayout();
        }
    }
}
```

When I arrive at the player (second) page, I waited for a minute and then hit a button (not shown) which would use `Debug.WriteLine()` to print out all contents of the list. It printed out the complete list.

So the async task is doing its job and completing the list, but it's not able to complete the listview properly.

I have 2 questions:

1. How do I get the listview to self-populate with more entries as list gets more items (perhaps in real time, where the remaining items from the list are continuously added to the listview until the list is completed?
2. Is there a faster way to get all the music files so I don't have to rely on this work-around?

Comment: For your first question: Use an observable collection instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25397664/how-to-notify-the-ui-that-its-property-changed-from-code-behind-wp8/25398330#25398330

Comment: For your second question, we need to find the slow down first.  How fast is that recursive call?  It that the main slow down?

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware It might be. How else could I find out?

Comment: You can use some type of profiler, but if you don't have a good one then just time using a Date.Now() before and after the event, then take the difference.

Comment: If traversing the directories and files is the main reason why you see that huge delay, then I would run it on a different thread.  If you do it this way it then you have to Dispatch Invoke to add to your ListView.